# Full table scan occured even when index exists?

Tags: sql, database, sybase

We have a sql query as follows

```
select * from Table where date < '20091010'
```

However when we look at the query plan, we see

The type of query is SELECT.

```
    FROM TABLE
        Worktable1.
    Nested iteration.
    Table Scan.
    Forward scan.
    Positioning at start of table.
    Using I/O Size 32 Kbytes for data pages.
    With MRU Buffer Replacement Strategy for data pages.
```

which seems to suggest that a full table scan is done. Why is the index not used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the majority of your dates are found by applying `< '20091010'` then the index may well be overlooked in favour of a table scan. What is your distribution of dates within that table? What is the cardinality? Is the index used if you only `select date` rather than `select *?`

Answer (score 2):

Unless the index is covering *, the optimizer realizes that a table scan is probably more efficient than an index seek/scan and bookmark lookup.  What's the expected selectivity of the date range?  Do you have a primary key defined?